# Want to get results of two queries in one single query by merging these queries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So, I've two tables, one is A(order_id, order_group_id, name), and second one is B(order_group_id, paid).

Table A have few records:

```
order_id | order_group_id | name
----------------------------------
1        | 0              | A
----------------------------------
2        | 14             | B
----------------------------------
3        | 0              | C
----------------------------------
4        | 15             | D
```

Table B have few records:

```
order_group_id | paid
--------------------------
14             | 0              
--------------------------
15             | 1
```

Now I am running these two queries:

```
SELECT order_id FROM A WHERE order_group_id = 0
```

and

```
SELECT d.order_id FROM A as d, B as e WHERE d.order_group_id = e.order_group_id AND e.paid = 0
```

First query is giving `order_id` `1` and `3`.

Second query is giving `order_id` `2`.

So, now how to get result of both these queries in single one, also these `order_id` should be in ascending order.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking, in the sense that your two queries do different thing and it's not clear how they are supposed to merge together. Do you need all orders where `order_id` is 0, or all orders where `paid` is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `LEFT JOIN`

This query will return all the records which has either `paid is 0` or the `order_group_id is 0`

```
SELECT order_id, e.paid,  d.order_group_id FROM A as d
LEFT JOIN B as e ON d.order_group_id = e.order_group_id
WHERE e.paid = 0 OR d.order_group_id = 0
```

In `codeignitor` you can achieve with the following by

```
$query = $this->select('SELECT order_id, e.paid,  d.order_group_id')->from('A as d')->join('B as e','d.order_group_id = e.order_group_id','LEFT')->where('e.paid = 0 OR d.order_group_id = 0')->get();
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b82f9/8

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT order_id FROM A WHERE order_group_id = 0
union
SELECT d.order_id FROM A as d, B as e WHERE d.order_group_id = e.order_group_id AND e.paid = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can relate two or more tables by using INNER JOIN. And use ORDER BY (column) ASC/DESC to make ascending or descending order

```
SELECT order_id FROM A as d INNER JOIN B as e 
ON d.order_group_id = e.order_group_id
WHERE d.order_group_id = 0 AND e.paid = 0
ORDER BY order_id ASC
```

Comment: INNER JOIN is used when there is a match between the tables, this misses the rows which OP wants.